# Elliptic function construction

Tags: complex-analysis

I know the methods to construct nonconstant elliptic function was given by Jacobi and Weirstrass .Is there any other method discovered for constructing elliptic functions?If yes, so where can I find?
Tell me references .

Comment: As quotients of theta functions?

Answer (score 0):

The following can be seen as a generalization of Jacobi elliptic functions expressed as inverses of integrals, so it may not be what you’re looking for.

For an orthogonal lattice you can map a rectangle to the upper half plane and and extend it by Schwarz’ reflection principle. Note that the elliptic function in this case is the inverse of the (multi-valued) Schwarz-Christoffel mapping that maps the upper half plane onto a rectangle.

This construction can be generalized: Let $p(z)$ be a polynomial of degree $3$ or $4$ with simple roots and $p(0)=0$. Then the multi-valued function $$z \mapsto \int_0^z \frac{\mathrm{d} w}{\sqrt{p(w)}}$$ has an elliptic function as single valued inverse. In this case the period lattice is given by the period integrals $$\int_{\gamma} \frac{\mathrm{d} w}{\sqrt{p(w)}}$$ where $\gamma$ is any closed path winding around an even number of roots of $p$.

Answer (score 0):

The book *Development of Elliptic Functions According to Ramanujan* by K. Venkatachaliengar edited by Shaun Cooper. The book *Elliptic Functions according to Eisenstein and Kronecker* by Andre Weil. The Wikipedia article [Abel elliptic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_elliptic_functions). There are other less well known approaches.